# Does the reputation system encourage competition as opposed to the sharing of information?

Tags: discussion

I read some of the blog and some of the meta threads and started thinking about the whole situation.  I also read some links a friend gave me in regards to some stuff Mozilla is looking at with testing for gender bias code reviews.

This got me to thinking about how I read and perceive questions on the site.  Usually when I read a question I'm looking for what the issue is, if it is stated clearly.  If it's not, I'll post comments asking questions about it.  Also I'll look for syntax errors or low hanging fruit to address in the comments.  I'm not above talking the issue out with the poster in the comments and nudging them towards the answer themselves, rather than posting an answer.  The way I see it, I'm not hard up for rep.  That's not really why I'm here.

However, I keep reflecting on that.  If there have been times when I've rushed to post an answer because I wanted to be the first to answer, potentially increasing my chance of getting the approved solution from the user.  I know there have been.  Apparently, I feel incentivized in some way that getting an answer posted quickly is more important, rather than going into great detail about the issue.  I do not want that to be how I answer questions, and I do try to provide details into the issue, but I'm sure I could provide more information than what I do.

So my question is more around how people view the reputation system on the site as being a possible contributor to the environment we are currently discussing.  Is it possible that we are making it more of a competition, rather than an undertaking of sharing information?  I'm not saying competition is bad.  I'm just thinking about the down sides to potentially having people in the mind set of needing to get the reputation, wanting to climb up the reputation ladders, treating questions/answers differently based upon the author's obtained reputation.

Reputation has functionality towards letting people gain access to features as they gain it.  But in actuality how important is that to other users?  How necessary is it for people asking questions to see an answer author's reputation?  Is it not enough for them to see the content of the answer, supported by the upvote/downvote system?  Could we potentially remove some of the (potential) bias with some added anonymity?

Comment: Fair warning, this might not be the best day to ask people about their feelings.

Comment: I think it's fair to say different people will most likely have different approaches towards working with questions.  I'm interested in the different view points, and how they believe the reputation system promotes their view point.

Comment: I can only anecdotally say about myself and from what I've seen others say over the years, that virtually nobody seems to be in it purely for the points. Personally, when I file an answer as quickly as possible it's purely out of an *I KNOW THIS!* feeling. I'm of course happy if that gets validated by a bunch of upvotes, but that's not the motivation I set out with. I'd give everyone the benefit of the doubt that that's the primary motivation for a lot of (most?) people.

Comment: @BilltheLizard are you sure that didn't come across as `unwelcoming`? he only has 9k rep..

Comment: We've already had people soul-searching about whether things like votes and duplicate closing are still relevant in these modern times, and now you want to question the virtual internet points that are the very basis of our existence? Is there no end to the indignities we are asked to suffer? ...but on a more serious note, that's touching at such a fundamental part of SO that I don't know if discussing it will go anywhere at all. Expect a lot of people who indirectly actually do care about the points on some level to go "of course I don't care about the points!"

Comment: "Does the reputation system encourage competition over the sharing of information?" yes.

Comment: A resounding "no" to this. Before SO, I spent my time on several  German programming forums. Over the years, they all descended into a pit of annoyed people yelling "RTFM!" entirely without the help of a reputation system.

Comment: Getting in early with a poor answer and then down-voting better ones while stealing their good ideas is a tried and tested route to success on SO.

Comment: @Pekka웃 the lack of a reputation system on those forums does not refute that one may contribute to a culture on another site.  The existence, or lack thereof, is not a variable in a vacuum.  I would suggest such an observation simply suggest that there are other contributing factors that can promote such an environment.  I could drink spoiled milk and get sick.  I could drink spoiled tea and get sick.  But by drinking spoiled tea and getting sick, I wouldn't turn around and say that is proof that drinking spoiled milk doesn't make me sick, since I didn't have milk in my second experiment.

Comment: @Bill the Lizard: How about now?

Comment: @BoltClock Oh yes, yes. Today seems much better. ;)

Comment: Related: [Fastest Gun in the West (FGITW)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19533#19533).

Comment: @Taplar the fact still remains that sharing information is the only way to gain significant points on this site, and downvoting, closevoting, and snarky comments do not gain you points. Quite the contrary - if you care for nothing but points, you LOVE easy questions that have been asked a million times before. Of course people can play stupid games like tactical downvoting, but show me one high-rep user who got big using such tactics. The rep system has its flaws, and people focus waaayyy too much on meaningless points, but overall it's worked extraordinarily well for almost a decade now.

Answer (score 12):

It is a common canard among people who feel Stack Overflow is hostile that people downvote, close-vote, and comment rudely for the purpose of maintaining their own reputation. To hoard those Internet points for themselves.

This is of course arrant nonsense.

Gamification is not responsible for incivility on Stack Overflow. While people have been known to downvote competing answers in order to give their answer greater visibility, people don't downvote questions as a way to get more views for their questions or answers. People do not gain rep by closing questions or by making snarky comments.

Aspects of gamification are in no way responsible for the hostility that Stack Overflow exhibits, no matter how you define "hostility". Indeed, it's quite the opposite.

You get rep for answering questions that get closed, so long as the answer gets upvoted. So answering quickly is better for your rep than closing or downvoting the question, both of which are considered by some to be "hostile".

Comment: i think the views of some one with a rep of 258k wont reflect the views of the majority

Comment: @smith: If you have an actual point to make, feel free to make it. But if all you're going to do is say that I'm not allowed to have an opinion because of my rep, well, I would call that a violation of the "Be Nice" policy.

Comment: were did i say you are  "not allowed to have an opinion" , WHERE??????????.

Comment: I think that it is rather rude to imply Nicol cannot remark about the correlation between gamification and the current environment being discussed based solely on his reputation. To be honest, someone who has contributed to the site for so long in such a positive way would if anything have a more insightful view of current environments and how gamification plays out. Voting lets us know the general consensus on meta, and that should be enough.

Comment: If anything some of the comments are addressing my question about if people treat questions/answers differently depending upon the authors reputation.

Comment: Agree with this, but it should be made clearer that it's arrant nonsense *because closevoting, downvoting, and commenting rudely does not earn you any rep ever, neither directly nor indirectly.* The only way to earn significant rep is by being helpful. Unlike @smith seems to believe, this is not an opinion like "is President X to blame for the deterioration of situation Y?". It just takes a look at the system's rules to see that it's not true.

Comment: It's not nonsense, I do it all the time.

Comment: @Pekka웃 There are web site posts providing instructions on how to tactical vote to increase your rep. It happens. its been discussed on meta before.

Answer (score 1):

I'd have a higher rep if this were true for me.  My approach is:

If I think I know something useful, then I will respond one way or another (comment or answer).

If it is just a pointer in the right direction, or if I don't have time for a detailed response, then I will just post a comment.

If I have time to post in the detail and quality I consider worthy of an answer, and there is no existing answer with similar content, then I'll do that instead.

If there is already an existing answer that's close to what I'd say, I'll add a comment to it instead of competing with it.